# Less-than full rank rectangular matrix P has a unique vector c s.t. Pc = 0-vector

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, matrix-rank

Below is a passage from a [computer vision paper on projective geometry](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~hartley/Papers/cheiral/revision/cheiral.pdf) (emphasis added):

> A projection from $P^3$ into $P^2$ is represented by a 3×4 matrix $P$,whereby
>   a point x maps to the point $u = Px$. It will be assumed that P has rank
>   3. **Since P has 4 columns but rank 3, there is a unique vector c such that $Pc = (0, 0, 0)^T$**. In other words, the projective transformation is
>   undefined at the point $c$, since $(0, 0, 0)^T$ is not a valid homogeneous
>   3-vector. The point $c$ will be called the perspective centre of the
>   camera.

NOTE: $P^3$ is 3D projective space and $P^2$ is 2D projective space. All that means is that the 3x4 matrix $P$ takes a 3D homogeneous point $(X,Y,Z,1)$ and produces a 2D projection $(x,y,1)$ of that point. Also, homogeneous in this context means having a non-zero last element.

Can someone please explain the bolded sentence to me? Does this have something to do with null space? Why is it that this vector $c$ must exist?

Comment: What is $P^3$ and $P^2$?

Comment: 3D projective space to 2D projective space. Sorry should have explained. I'll edit it

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Also, context aside, the algebra itself if where I'm lost. I'm missing the motivation as to why the rank implies that there must be some vector $c$ that produces the 0-vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a $3\times4$ matrix $A\colon\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ must have a non-trivial nullspace: i.e., there must be at least one nonzero vector $u$ for which $Au=0$. This intuitively follows from the fact that we are going down a dimension, so we have to completely collapse at least one direction. In this situation however, there necessarily is infinitely many such vectors, since by linearity, $A(\lambda u)=\lambda Au=\lambda 0=0$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. The fact that you are in projective space, however, geometrically means we are actually sitting on the unit sphere, and so when we project down a dimension, assuming only *one* dimension gets collapsed, then there can only be one such *unit* vector $u$ on the unit sphere such that $Pu=0$.

Comment: $n-$dimensional projective space is obtained as all "directions" in $n+1-$dimensional real space, so since geometrically we identify "directions" with "unit vectors", $n-$dimensional projective space can be identified with the $n-$dimensional sphere.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that for me!

Comment: You're welcome, and computer vision/vision in general/how we perceive the universe all have mind-bending mathematical implications when you think about the difference between the actual existence of an object, and the projection onto our eyes that is perceived. A lot of awesome philosophical exercises can come from the theory of vision...